# Backspace key not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I was trying to set custom auto import shortcut in Android studio. I added <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> as a shortcut. Since then my backspace key has stopped working.
Please suggest How can I resolve this problem. 
I don't want to change my IDE settings to default.

Comment: Now I cant able to update it. Can u tell how to remove custom keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reset whole settings. Just go to keymap settings again, highlight that entry with <kbd>Del</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and press right mouse button, then choose "Remove Del + Enter" and remove this assignment.